# cannot see any output of ansible playbook

Tags: bash, shell, ansible

i'm going crazy, i'm a newbie of ansible.
i'm trying to execute a script on a remote node and return as output, the output of that script.

So i do this script inside remote node

```
#!/bin/bash
su - zimbra -c 'cat /var/log/zimbra.log | sed -n 's/.*sasl_username=//p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n'
```

and i put this script on /root/spammer.sh and i've give to this script execution permission.

On my ansible node i've created that playbook spammer.yaml

```
- hosts: zimbra1
  tasks:
    - name: see spammer
      shell : /root/spammer.sh
```

so if i play this playbook i've this output :

```
PLAY 1: ZIMBRA1
task 2: zimbra1
```

instead a list of email address (filtered by /var/log/zimbra.log)
why i don't have any output?

zimbra1 on task2 is yellow.

Thanks for your support

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/537060/how-to-see-stdout-of-ansible-commands

Comment: i've already see this but also if i register output and use debug to print msg, i've always same error

Comment: i've made same playbook on that post :
    - hosts: zimbra1
      tasks:
        - name: Vedere spammer
          command: echo "hello"
          register: hello
    
        - debug: msg="{{ hello.stdout }}"
        - debug: msg="{{ hello.stderr }}"

but i've no output again

Comment: Have you tried using -vv or -vvv when executing.  It gives verbose output for plays being executed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case recommended solution is to add debug with var

```
  - hosts: zimbra1
tasks:
  - name: see spammer
    shell : /root/spammer.sh
    register: spam
  
  - debug:
    var: spam
```

This form will show you all details about script, usually use stderr to show messages.